# Add search by customer IP address to Woocommerce order search

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've been trying to find a solution for this but couldn't.

Woocommerce saves customer IP addresses when creating orders.

However, it's not possible to search orders by an IP address.

How would I add this functionality to woocommerce order search?

Comment: Have you done any research? Please share your efforts with us.

Comment: Obviously, you should edit your plugin directly if you don't care about the plugin updates. If plugin supports extensions - you can use it's API to inject the code. Otherwise, you can write your own small plugin with some simple SQLs for search + UI that refers to original plugin.

Answer (score 1):

- Inspired by [Add search by customer IP address to Woocommerce order search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53140009/add-search-by-customer-ip-address-to-woocommerce-order-search)
- Code idea borrowed from https://www.skyverge.com/blog/filtering-woocommerce-orders/ && https://gist.github.com/bekarice/41bce677437cb8f312ed77e9f226a812

https://gist.github.com/ramonfincken/8a671dcaa496425b4d37782cb7c21701

Comment: In which file we should need to add this php function ?

Comment: preferrably in your child theme functions.php file or in your custom plugin

Comment: I think the format of this has changed with HPOS enabled.  See https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/High-Performance-Order-Storage-Upgrade-Recipe-Book